# WPF: Skinning with Images

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, skinning, skin

There are a lot of samples around showing how to skin WPF applications using DynamicResources and ResourceDictionaries loaded dynamically from .xaml files.

My problem is that my skins use images and I would like to include the style definitions and the images in a single file, so that a user only needs to download this.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Is there a way to pack multiple resources?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276055/dynamically-change-implicit-style/8995318#8995318

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating DLL of a theme, I mean separate DLL project with image and style resource file embedded in that. The only limitation is that it doesn't allow developer to modify the Style.. Hope this helped you