# Dynamically change implicit style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Right now I have some TabItems in my App which are implicitly styled.  I want to add a "Night mode" to my app and change my style.  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfonso was right in idea...
but you have to do it like this in WPF

```
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear(); 
Uri uri = new Uri("/Resources/GlassButton5Night.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
var resDict = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resDict);
```

And you have make sure you reset your MergedDictionaries at the right level

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with merged dictionaries. Put all your "normal" styles in a dictionary and add it to the app resources by default:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Normal.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can remove the current dictionary and load another one dynamically:

```cs
private void ChangeStyles()
{
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    StreamResourceInfo resInfo = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Styles/NewStyles.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    XDocument xaml = XDocument.Load(resInfo.Stream);
    ResourceDictionary resource = XamlReader.Load(xaml.ToString()) as ResourceDictionary;

    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);
}
```

Comment: XamlReader.Load doesn't take a string as arg.  At least in 4.0

Comment: Sorry, I took that code from a Silverlight project. In WPF it takes an XmlReader, which can be build from the stream using XmlReader.Create.